# Is MacBook powerful enough to do Ipad development? or do I need a MacBook Pro?

Tags: ipad

The title probably says it all.

Considering an ipad's processor is nothing compared to a macbook, I would think a Macbook should be more than capable to run the simulator. However, not knowing much about iphone/ipad development, I'd like to get some opinions on this.

for e.g. how many apps are typically need to be run for ipad dev (editor, debugger, perf monitor, trace log, etc). are these apps resource (memory, cpu) intensive?

please do not take into consideration the actual image, 3d, video, sound development. I understand one would need quite a beefy machine to produce these type of creative assets. What I'm looking at is a machine to do code development, physics, putting together the produced assets (images, vector graphics, 3d video, sound, etc).

Comment: Build the app on the worst machine possible.  If it performs on there, it will perform on the target.

Comment: eventhough performance testing will be an important part of the dev cycle, I am more concern about the whole development experience at this point.

Comment: as per my comment: screen size will be the biggest factor in the "whole development experience"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Macbook would be sufficient for development - slightly longer compile times will be the only downside - but that should not really be significant. However, where you're going to struggle will be screen estate. The Macbook's resolution is only just larger than the iPad's in landscape (and by the time you take out the dock and taskbar, perhaps smaller). In portrait be prepared for a lot of scrolling.
I started using the iPad simulator on my 15.4" Macbook Pro originally and got so frustrated with it I went out and bought a 17" instead (even knowing they're due for a refresh). YMMV.

Of course, if you'll have the MB hooked up to a monitor most of the time this may not be an issue.

Comment: A new monitor is about 1/20th the price of a new laptop, especially considering you already own one! You must have more money than sense.

Comment: Difficult to lug the monitor on the train. Then there's the question of where to plug it in ;-)
I do a lot of my coding out of my home/ office. At home I have a 30" Cinema Display (which cost more than half the price of the new laptop, btw :-) )

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a MacBook is fine, since as you observe compiling, editing, etc are relatively low-powered tasks compared to image and video editing.

Since the iPad development software is all part of the standard development toolkit and SDK, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: do you think I will be missing out on anything (ipad dev wise) by opting for a macbook?

Answer (score 2):

I develop on an intel core solo mac mini and it is plenty powerful enough to do iPad development.

Comment: thats a relief. I just ordered one and after reading this thread was a bit scared that I made a wrong choice.

Answer (score 1):

I develop exclusively on MacBook Pro 15" - and an older model at that (2.33 GHz). I agree with others that an external monitor is extremely helpful. I have a 24" monitor in addition to MBP's 15". On the road, I continue development work without aid of external monitor.

Speed is less than ideal - but a lot depends on what you are used to. I am considering upgrading to newly announced MBP 15".

As for applications. Most of what you need is in Xcode and the iPhone Simulator. But you will find yourself running Interface Builder and Shark from time to time.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing on a MacBook Air (2.13 GHz), with that handy external portrait display. Since most iPhone OS code bases don't make heavy use of C++ and templates, you shouldn't have any compile time problems with a lesser machine.